# Access JQuery Filled dropdown list value from code behind

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have fetched the drop down list items using jquery and web methods. How to access the drop down list selected value from code behind or server side?

Comment: using val() or property value of SELECT element. To get it server side, you have to send it to the server using for example ajax

Comment: please post what you've tried and the code you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

```
//we can assign the selected value of the dropdownlist in the following way,
$('#ddlSuppliers').change(function () {                
    $("#Label1").html($("#" + '<%=ddlSuppliers.ClientID %>').val());
    return false;
});
```

in this case, i have used a label. 
Note: See to it that the label and dropdown list are in update pannel.